# WordPress YouTube Playlists Random Function

Tags: wordpress, iframe, random, embed, playlist

I'm attempting to concatenate a random variable inside an iframe for WordPress in the editor and is not working,  always show me the first video of my playlist, actually i want to update a different  video for my playlist each time  when someone is in our website 
my javascript looks like this

```
'<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/?list=PL428169F9EB17A5F8&amp;index=' + rand(0,3) + '" width="320" height="180" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>'
```

Any Help?

Comment: What's actually the problem?

Comment: is not working Andy, i used it in the WordPress editor as you seen and always show me the first video of my playlist

Comment: Well, you could try putting that information in your question. This site works best when people post clear questions, with specific problems that can be answered. Unfortunately I don't have a clue about this particular problem - I was just going through and reviewing new questions.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress limits the capability to [post iframes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html) freely. It's admin-only. It can be turned off, but the best solution is to [create Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), so the user just have to add `[something]` into the content and the iframe will print without issues.

```
add_shortcode( 'rand_yt', 'rand_so_25319303' );

function rand_so_25319303( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    $output = sprintf(
        '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/?list=PL428169F9EB17A5F8&amp;index=%s" width="320" height="180" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>', 
        rand(0,3) 
    );
    return $output;
}
```

Another option is to add `<?php echo do_shortcode('rand_yt'); ?>` to a theme template.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo for your reply, however i am not skilled in this kind of code and i only copy and past it in my portal where i have the administrator profile, and doesn't work. Still given me the same video all time even when i save the changes and refresh the web page, any sugestion?